# Angular 6, How test parent emitter on child component?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, subscription, eventemitter

I have a tab component as a wrapper with their child components, the wrapper component emits the state (open or close) and the index of each tab, On each child component I inject the wrapper component to have access to the emitter.

So basically I'm trying to subscribe to the emitter from my wrapper component on my child component test file:

```
it(`it should have a 'toggle()' function that close/open the tab and then emits the tab status`, (emitted) => {

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AccordionTabComponent);
    const compiled = fixture.componentInstance;

    compiled.toggle(); // -> toggle function trigger the emit

    const data = {
      tabIndex: compiled.tabIndex,
      isOpen: compiled.isOpen
    }; // -> I get the current data from the child component to compare it with the emitted data.

    compiled.accordionRef.open.subscribe(tabEmmited => {
      console.log('tabEmmited: ', tabEmmited);
      expect(JSON.stringify(data)).toBe(JSON.stringify(tabEmmited));
      emitted();
    });

    fixture.detectChanges();    
});
```

But looks like the subscription never happens because the 'log' inside the 'subscribe' never prints anything and that also causes this error:

```
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

**Here's some code from my components to get more context:**

Wrapper component:

```
 export class AccordionComponent implements OnInit {

  @ContentChildren(forwardRef(() => AccordionTabComponent)) public childrenTabs: QueryList<AccordionTabComponent>;
  @Output() open: EventEmitter<{}> = new EventEmitter(); // -> Parent emitter.
 }
```

Tab Component:

```
    export class AccordionTabComponent implements OnInit {
        accordionRef: AccordionComponent; -> Wrapper Component Ref
        tabIndex: number;
        isOpen: boolean;

        constructor(
          @Inject(AccordionComponent) accordionContainer: AccordionComponent -> Wrapper component injected
      ) {
            this.accordionRef = accordionContainer;
          }

      // Show/Hide tab
        toggle(): void {
          this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
          this.accordionRef.open.emit({tabIndex: this.tabIndex, isOpen: this.isOpen});
        }
     }
```

Comment: You emit before subscribing to the emitter. So the event has already been emitted when you subscribe.

Comment: Thanks, The test is working great now.

Comment: Maybe try to subscribe first and `toggle` after ?

Answer (score 1):

You should be subscribing to the event emitter, before your code actually emits it. So that you don't miss out the event.

```
it(`it should have a 'toggle()' function that close/open the tab and then emits the tab status`, (emitted) => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AccordionTabComponent);
    const compiled = fixture.componentInstance;

    //subscribe before emitting
    compiled.accordionRef.open.subscribe(tabEmmited => {
          expect(JSON.stringify(data)).toBe(JSON.stringify(tabEmmited));
    });

    compiled.toggle(); // -> Call the method that actually emits it

    ..........

    fixture.detectChanges();    
});
```